# Anim.SetFloat doesn't work

Tags: c#, windows

I am getting this error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>
> UnityEditor.Graphs.AnimationStateMachine.GraphGUI.SyncGraphToUnitySelection (Boolean force) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Graphs/UnityEditor.Graphs/AnimationStateMachine/GraphGUI.cs:310)
>   UnityEditor.Graphs.AnimatorControllerTool.DetectAnimatorControllerFromSelection () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Graphs/UnityEditor.Graphs/Animation/AnimatorControllerTool.cs:734)
>   UnityEditor.Graphs.AnimatorControllerTool.OnEnable () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Graphs/UnityEditor.Graphs/Animation/AnimatorControllerTool.cs:747)

Here is my code (unity 2017.3.0f3)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float moveSpeed;

    private Animator anim;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0.5f || Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < -0.5f)
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f));          
        }

        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") > 0.5f || Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") < -0.5f)
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f));
        }
    }

    anim.SetFloat("MoveX", Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"));
    anim.SetFloat("MoveY", Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")); 
}
```

Comment: How did this code even compile? The anim.setfloat should be inside of a method, but to your problem, check that the this script and the animator are attached to the same GameObject in the hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works, but you can try this:

```
public GameObject animObject;
private Animator anim;

void Start () {
anim = animObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
}
```

In "animObject" get the animator of the GameObject that you are intending to animate.

Comment: Thanks but now I have another problem Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs(29,18): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: I think that `anim.SetFloat("MoveX", Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"));
        anim.SetFloat("MoveY", Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));` Should be inside void Update